# Create Line Graph with Dynamic Range based on values in columns of Dates from January that ends at YTD & be able to select which Clients are displayed

Tags: dynamic, charts, range, ytdl

Been banging my head against the keyboard on this one.
I'm trying to create a dynamic Line Graph based on the below data and I'd like to avoid using VBA, if possible:

[image: DataRange]

The "Title" column is the clients to display and the Date values make up the lines. There could be 3 clients or there could be 12. It varies. There are formulas going 30 rows down from the title row all the way through to "26-Dec" pulling from a raw data list, so those blank rows below TMKOMS actually have formulas in them.

I want a dynamic range that includes only the clients that are visible in the Title column.
On the Line Graph, I want a way to be able to select which client(s) to display (ie. drop-down boxes, check boxes or something).

I also need the Date range of values to dynamically capture "3-Jan" up to the year-to-date (eg. "21-Mar"), so that the Line Graph will only display up to 21-Mar. It would also be nice to have a way for users to select any one of the dates from a drop-down, but if the drop-down is blank, the dynamic range reverts to the year-to-date automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: LineGraphExample]

---

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving all this by breaking down and using VBA to set autofilters.